# Shared memory with pointer in C#

Tags: c#, ipc, shared-memory

[MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=net-6.0) seems to be the only way to share memory between processes in .NET(?), however I didn't find a way to map a region to the process' virtual memory space, so it can't be really treated as a memory block since there's no way to get the pointer.
I'm using pointer to process bitmap for best performance and reusability.

[In c++ this can be easily achieved using boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).

Is there a way share a region of memory between processes and use pointer to read/write data?

Comment: The documentation you linked shows you how to create the accessor: `using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))` - You can use `accessor` [to read and write value type items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemoryaccessor?view=net-6.0) (which includes POCO structs) to and from the MMF at any offset.

Comment: For lower level access you can use [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.safememorymappedviewhandle?view=net-6.0) which returns a [`SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safememorymappedviewhandle?view=net-6.0) which has a load of lower level access methods. It even has `AcquirePointer(Byte*)` which returns a pointer to the start of the MMF view - but that requires `unsafe` code.

Comment: Thanks! The second one is exactly what I was looking for. I don't really mind using unsafe context. Would you like you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lower level access you can use [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.safememorymappedviewhandle?view=net-6.0) which returns a [`SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safememorymappedviewhandle?view=net-6.0)  which has a load of lower level access methods.

Here's an example:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Open an MMF of 16MB (not backed by a system file; in memory only).
    using var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("mmfMapName", capacity: 16 * 1024 * 1024);

    // Create an MMF view of 8MB starting at offset 4MB.
    const int VIEW_BYTES = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
    using var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset: 4 * 1024 * 1024, VIEW_BYTES);

    // Get a pointer into the unmanaged memory of the view. 
    using var handle = accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle;

    unsafe
    {
        byte* p = null;

        try
        {
            // Actually get the pointer.
            handle.AcquirePointer(ref p);

            // As an example, fill the memory pointed to via a uint*
            for (uint* q = (uint*)p; q < p + VIEW_BYTES; ++q)
            {
                *q = 0xffffffff;
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            if (p != null)
                handle.ReleasePointer();
        }
    }
}
```